# List not emitting on remove item (RxKotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, reactive-programming, rx-kotlin

I'm working on an Android App. I have a list of photos loaded in memory. I want to make use of Reactive library, so I declare a memory-base datasource where I save the list:

```
    @Singleton
    class MemoryPhotosSource @Inject constructor() {
         var photos: MutableList<Image> = mutableListOf()
         ...

         // Here is my function to add items to list.
         fun addPhoto(image: Image) {
              photos.add(image)
         }

         // Here is my function to list the items.
         fun listPhotos(): List<Image> = photos

         // Here is my function to remove items from list.
         fun removePhoto(image: Image): Image {
               photos.remove(image)
               return image
         }
    }
```

Then, I have a ViewModel where I call these methods:

```
class CreateDocumentFromPhotosViewModel @Inject constructor(): ViewModel() {
       @Inject
       lateinit var source: MemoryPhotosSource

       fun listImages(): Observable<List<Image>> = Observable.fromCallable {
           source.listPhotos()
       }.applySchedulers()

       fun addImage(image: Image) {
           source.addPhoto(image)
       }

       fun removeImage(image: Image): Image {
           source.removePhoto(image)
           return image
       }
}
```

Finally, I subscribe in my application:

```
    dis add viewModel.listImages()
            .subscribe {
                adapter.data = it
            }

    dis add onDelete
            .map { viewModel.removeImage(it) }
            .map { showSnackbar(parentView, resources.getString(R.string.document_removed), resources.getString(R.string.undo), it)}
            .map { it.subscribe { viewModel.addImage(it) } }
            .subscribe()
```

Listing and adding images work nicely. However, when I press the delete button, which publish in the onDelete subject, the snackbar is shown, but no change is performed to the RecyclerView adapter. Debugging, I noticed that the `removePhoto` function is being called in `MemoryPhotosSource` class, and the list is being successfuly modified. However, it does not emit the changes, that's why the RecyclerView is not updated. I confirmed this behavior by leaving the application and entering again, which forced the repainting of the Recycler, and then, the removed element didn't show up, as it should be. So, I think the problem is the list doesn't emit the changes when an item is removed.

Does anybody know a way to solve this? Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should use [defer operator](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/defer.html)  while creating your observable list. It returns refresh list when you subscribed.

Comment: Hi, @gokhan,  thanks for your answer. This means I would have to subscribe multiple times to the observer?

Comment: @SebastiánLandínezGarcía Nope I mean wrap callable object with defer operator

Comment: I'm quite new to Rx library. Does this mean I should do my listImages function equal to Observable.fromCallable {...}.defer? Or perform some compose operation? Thanks!